# assign a module to each individual page in multipage article

Tags: joomla3.0

Joomla modules can be assigned to pages in the dashboard using the Menu Assignment tab.

When editing an article in the article manager in the dashboard I can add 'page breaks' to the article in order to divide the article up into two or more pages.

The 'page break' option also automatically creates its own menu for each individual page in the multipage article. But when trying to assign a module to one of these individual pages using the Menu Assignment tab, the menu item created by page break doesn't show up in the list of menu items on the site.

I believe that individual pages of a multipage article are not stored in the database in the same way as separate articles? So is it possible to assign a module to an individual page within a multipage article?

Comment: Have you tried anything or expecting some ready-made code?

Comment: Hi Nadeem - Thanks for the quick answer. Actually what I want to do is to assign a different Custom HTML module to each page of a multipage article. The idea is to create a different header for each individual page in the module position (position 1) in my template. I really would like each individual header to be displayed in this position, which is why I am trying to do this with custom HTML modules.

Comment: Now that's some clarification.. can you just edit the question and paste all the details there plz ;)